# puppet agent -test is not generating certificates

Tags: puppet

I have configured puppet master as explained in https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html.

I started and it's running as, (Master cert has been generated to correctly to the hostname correctly)

`[root@puppetmaster private_keys]# ps -aef | grep puppet
j2ee       2162   2160  0 08:08 ?        00:00:04 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/home/j2ee/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/j2ee/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/home/j2ee/.local/share/akonadi/socket-puppetmaster.ms.com/mysql.socket
puppet     2981      1  0 08:49 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/puppet master  --no-daemonize
root       3292   2527  0 09:37 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto puppet`

And puppet master is listening to port 8140

`tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:8140   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN    2981/ruby`

But I am unable to generate create certificate signing requests from puppet agents.

`[root@puppetagent1 j2ee]# puppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled`

can some one help me to identify / Debug this issue ?

Appreciate any one can introduce me a good complete tutorial to configure puppet masters and agents, I have followed this http://middlewaresnippets.blogspot.co.nz/2015/03/configure-linux-using-puppet.html and it's a good uscase/tutorial but I feel something missing on installing and configuring puppet-agent, may be I am wrong. (Not sure what would be the puppet.conf for puppet agent )

Thanks !

Comment: Thats a dns lookup error it looks like. Do you have a hosts file entry for your puppet master on the agent?

Comment: Thanks, It's firewall on puppet master, it's worked fine when i fixed the firewall. Do you know any good tutorial which explains puppet agent puppet.conf configurations ( not puppet Enterprise )

Comment: The official docs: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html

Comment: Questions for tutorials and reference documentation are not really appropriate here. That being said, I did write that book... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Elike!

Check on client side if you have communication with server by using ping and after telnet on port 8140 (default), collecting server from config:

`puppet config print | grep -w server`

After check the certificate name for the client:

`puppet config print certname`

And after, remove the directory of ssl files and dirs:

`puppet config print | grep ssldir`

`rm -rf <ssldir_output>`

On Server side, remove all information about the client node as root:

`puppet node clean <clientServerName>`

`puppet node deactivate <clientServerName>`

`puppet cert --revoke <clientCertName>`

`puppet cert --clean <clientCertName>`

On client side again, call puppet agent test:

`puppet agent --test --waitforcert 60`

Go to server, list and sign the client certificate:

`puppet cert --list`

`puppet cert --sign <commandAboveOutput>` (Just the client server name)

On client side the puppet will continue and start the configuration.

Comment: Your interest in contributing is welcome!  However, do note that (1) this question is over 5 years old, and (2) the OP remarked in comments that they resolved it (by opening the firewall on the master).

Comment: Thank you, John! I was searching for an answer for this problem and the information was spread in several sites. I use the opportunity to help others. I need to understand better the stack overflow. I just started to contribute.